# Raspbian Jessie can't log in SFTP as root

Tags: raspbian

I had raspbian whezy on my Rpi2, but decide to upgrade to jessie. I'm glad with this change... But...

After fresh install, I have changed password of user pi and root.

I have allways used winscp and log as root on whezy version, but I can't do it with Jessie

What I have to do to enable log as root with sftp?

Answer (score 1):

Set `PermitRootLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
It's a security risk and therefor I recommend you **not** to do it and that's exactly why the default was changed.
But, it's your system.

Comment: I just want to do this, because I need to change some files via SFTP. And if I log as Pi or other user, I don't have necessary privileges to change some files. I'm not very good under command line (vi or nano), so I prefer to do trough SFTP.